# JQuery UI autocomplete on iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Has anyone ever tried to develop an autocomplete input with JQuery UI for iPad web app?

I use JQuery mobile and added JQuery UI to do the autocomplete. It works fine on Firefox but not on iPad.

Is there any limitation or incompatibility?

Comment: I've got it working, but scrolling filtered records really sucks. I'd love to see a more elegant solution for the iPad.

Comment: Which version do you use? Could you post your solution?
I finally changed my app not to use autocomplete but your solution may interest other developers.