# Autocomplete Library - Cross browser/mobile compatible

Tags: android, ios, autocomplete, cross-browser, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can anyone suggest an autocomplete library which is compatible with the major desktop browsers as well as iOS/Android phones & tablets?

I've had a look at a few options and am currently using jQuery autocomplete but this is not working correctly on iPhone/iPad

I also looked at Twitter typehead but read that mobile browsers are not supported and some people have had problems with this

Surely, being that a suggestion box is such as common function there must be something cross browser/device compatible?

All I'm after is something that would work with:

- Relatively new versions of desktop browsers
- iPhone/iPad
- Android phones/tablets

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried finding fixes for jQuery autocomplete. Might be easier than looking for a new solution? What is the issue on iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going into your question let me [list](http://techslides.com/list-of-autocomplete-plugins-and-libraries) some autocomplete libraries :

- typeahead.js fast autocomplete library from Twitter
- complete.ly JavaScript library for autocompletion
- Marco Polo jQuery Autocomplete plugin
- bassistance jQuery Autocomplete Plugin
- jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget
- jQuery TextEXT Tag Input and Autocomplete
- YUI Autocomplete
- jQuery TokenInput Autocomplete
- jQuery Manifest Input Autocomplete
- Inputosaurus Text Input with Autocomplete
- Live Search 2.0 with Ajax
- Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery
- glAutoTag lightweight auto-complete and tags plugin for jQuery
- Autocomplete Widget for jQuery Mobile
- Autosuggest jQuery Plugin
- jQuery Cool Auto-Suggest
- dhtmlxCombo JavaScript combobox with autocomplete
- VisualSearch.js enhances search boxes with autocomplete faceted
  search queries
- jQuery PHP Ajax Autosuggest
- SearchBox jQuery live search autocomplete
- FCBKcomplete facebook-like dynamic inputs with auto complete
- selectToAutocomplete enhances select tags with autocomplete features
- jQuery Plugin Auto Complete
- jQuery Smart Auto Complete plugin
- Select2 jQuery select tag with autocomplete features
- selectize.js textbox and select box hybrid with autocomplete
- Ajax Search Suggest
- Autocompleter for MooTools with JSON, PHP, and MySQL PDO
- Simple Ajax Live Search
- Search suggestion with PHP and MySQL

But the list may not satisfy every compatibility that you may require,i would rather recommend to have used [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) , Autocomplete [Doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/)

> I've had a look at a few options and am currently using jQuery
>   autocomplete but this is not working correctly on iPhone/iPad

Stack Overflow posts on issues and solutions for ipad / iphones in jQuery auto-complete :

[Autocomplete requires you to click twice in iOS after update to 1.11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286685/autocomplete-requires-you-to-click-twice-in-ios-after-update-to-1-11-0)

[jquery autocomplete ipad hide keyboard focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246491/jquery-autocomplete-ipad-hide-keyboard-focus)

[JQuery UI autocomplete on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958649/jquery-ui-autocomplete-on-ipad)

[jQuery UI autocomplete needs double tap on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400334/jquery-ui-auto-complete-need-double-tap-on-ios)

Stack Overflow and other references on implementation :

[Getting jQueryUi Autocomplete to work with jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994865/getting-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-work-with-jquerymobile)

[JQuery Autocomplete working in Chrome but not in android using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656573/jquery-autocomplete-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-android-using-phonegap)

[detecting and disabling autocompletion on mobile devices with either complete.ly or typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964161/detecting-and-disabling-autocompletion-on-mobile-devices-with-either-complete-ly)

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

[Tap head auto suggestion](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/tap-ahead-design-pattern-mobile-auto-suggest-on-steroids/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)